# Create an integer from a dict inside a list. Python newbie

Tags: python

I get the following object from a Google Analytics API response (simplified) which appears to be a list with a dict inside it:

```
max_value = [{u'values': [u'1647']}]
```

I simply want to extract [u'1647'] as a stand-alone integer object, but I've contorted myself into the following very ugly Python code to do so:

```
for i in max_value:
    temp = int(i['values'].pop(0))
    print temp
    print isinstance(temp, int)
```

Yields:

```
1647
TRUE
```

I've searched for some time and all I see is the ability to turn a list of strings into a list of integers. I don't want a resulting list. I want a single var object, as above.

The code works, but I'm obviously missing something very simple here. My code is way too ugly... help. TIA.

Comment: It's not gonna get better than `temp = int(max_value[0]['values'][0])`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey You should post that as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `temp = int(max_value[0]['values'][0])`.

There's no better option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
max_value = [{u'values': [u'1647']}]
for i in max_value:
    print(int(i[u"values"][0])) #or  print(int(i["values"][0]))
```

Comment: you have missed the last parenthesis. It should be `print(int(i[u"values"][0]))`

Answer (score 0):

The code in @Aran-Fey' comment is the best solution here

But here is another option:

```
max_value = [{u'values': [u'1647']}]
print(int(list(dict(*max_value).values())[0][0]))
```

Output:

```
1647
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have single value:

```
intValue = int(max_value[0]['values'][0])
print(intValue)
```

If you have multiple values:

```
for values in max_value:
  intValue = int(values['values'][0])
  print(intValue)
```